# Is there a relation between Gap energy and Fermi energy?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, fermi-energy

Are Gap energy and Fermi energy in semi conductors co-dependent variables? If yes, what's the relationship between them?

Answer (score 2):

The bandgap energy is the difference between two levels, the valence band edge and the conduction band edge.

The Fermi level is a particular energy level, the level at which, if there were a state at that level, the state would have a 50% probability of occupancy.

In order for a material to be considered a semiconductor, the Fermi level must lie within the band gap. That is, somewhere between the valence band edge and the conduction band edge. So you could write a relationship

$$ 0 < E_f - E_v < E_g$$

where $E_v$ is the maximum energy level in the valence band.

Typically in intrinsic semiconductors, the Fermi level is quite close to the middle of the band gap. This is a consequence of the detailed balance requirement and the valence and conduction bands' E-k relationships not having too different a curvature.

When doping is introduced, it tends to shift the Fermi level towards one band edge or the other. With *degenerate doping*, the Fermi level may actually move below the valence band edge or above the conduction band edge.

Answer (score 0):

The simple approximation is $ E_F = \frac{E_c - E_v}{2} $ in undoped semiconductor but it should be noticed that Fermi levels change with dopant e.g.  $ E_F = \frac{E_c - E_v}{2} +\frac{1}{2} kT \ln{\frac{N_v}{N_c}}. $